# Switching a team from Git Merge to Rebase

Tags: git, workflow, git-merge, git-rebase

Our R&D works with two central repos, originally started by very stubborn smart people, one works with rebases and the other with gitflow and merges. While I'm very comfortable in using merges and I see most github projects use that modality, there's pressure on us to conform to "rebase", as we are moving to a more organized Gerrit code review system and many developers are coming over to our repo from the other team.

So here it is: I'm warned by the man pages never to mix rebasing and merging, now I have to switch my entire team. I wonder how to do that without too much risk to the stability of our code. people always have an open feature branch or two, and during development may merge from dev multiple times. are such feature branches OK to just switch to rebasing or should the cutoff day be only after all feature branches have been merged first and no branches exist out there with merges in their history since fork? How do I plan this as a smooth transition?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in mixing merge and rebase I see is that when you do a rebase it "linearizes" the history, and this doesn't work very well with merge commits. But the linearization itself actually has it own merits as history becomes simpler and easier to reason about.

The simplest strategy is to **avoid merges** indeed. At the moment when one would earlier say `git merge X` do `git rebase X` instead.

This isn't that bad except when you have several commits in your local branch and one of them gives a merge conflict upon rebase. Further commits to the same spot could yield the same merge conflict again and again. The workaround in such case could be to abort the rebase `git rebase --abort` and either rearrange local commits with `git rebase --interactive` or squash local commits (`git reset $(git merge-base HEAD X)`). Repeat the rebase afterwards.

Special care when doing rebases shall be paid to the shared branches. Human synchronization will be required when rebasing those, and many would prefer to avoid it at all, see below:

Another approach is to **accept merges** from upstream during the development and do **squash** before merging back / making pull request, e.g.:

```
 git checkout -b Work
 #work...commit...commit..
 git merge X
 #work...commit...commit..
 git merge X
 git reset X && git add . && git commit -m 'All my work squashed'
 #alternatively the last part might be like this:
 git checkout X && git merge --squash Work
```

The pro of this approach is that you can have such branch relatively safely shared without the overhead of human communication. It is also often easier to resolve conflicts when merging two branches than when replaying one branch on top of another.

Comment: P.S. hope you guys know what you're doing when considering moving to Gerrit.

Comment: I wish I had a say on that, it's a major international corporation and we got that requirement from above. so far we've been using Atlassian Stash, but we need slightly tighter code review rules. Gerrit may be an overkill for some situations, is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Gerrit tends to become more of a disabling rather than an enabling tool in my experience.

Comment: Might also be worth checking out [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) (reuse recorded resolution of conflicted merges) to solve the problem of repeatedly getting the same merge conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you need to understand and use both merge and rebase to work with git (and especially in gerrit).

Some examples...

You would merge when you uplift your feature branch to a fresh remote master. This gives minimal uplift work and it's easy to follow the history of the feature development in for example gitk.

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/my_feature
git merge origin/master
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/my_feature
```

You would merge when you prepare a delivery commit (with `--squash` option as no merge commits are allowed in `master`).

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git merge --squash origin/my_feature
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

You would rebase when a delivery commit fails integration for whatever reason and you need to update it towards a fresh remote master.

```
git fetch
git fetch <gerrit link>
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
git rebase origin/master
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```